# Command not found, but works with sudo

Tags: debian, zsh, sudo, shutdown, reboot

I installed Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) x86_64 without a GUI and created a user and gave it sudo access. The user does have sudo access, but commands like `shutdown` or `reboot` only work when using sudo. In my experience, I never needed to run these commands using sudo. How can I fix it?

```
$ whoami
amir
$ id amir
uid=1000(amir) gid=1000(amir) groups=1000(amir),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev)
$ reboot
zsh: command not found: reboot
$ sudo which reboot
/usr/sbin/reboot
$ sudo grep amir /etc/sudoers
amir    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
$ sudo grep "^sudo" /etc/sudoers
sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: It's because non-root on debian doesn't start with /sbin or /usr/sbin in PATH.

Comment: even if they're in the PATH, reboot and shutdown won't do anything (except print an error message) if you run them without root privs.   Just being a member of the sudo group (or having sudo access via other /etc/sudoers rules) is not the same as actually running something with sudo. It means that your user is capable of running something with sudo, not that you have root privs at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the default configuration of your PATH variable.  PATH sets where the shell will search for a particular command.

By default on Debian `sudo` will change your PATH.  This is partially done for security.  But here it's also adding a couple of things for you.

Namely it adds: `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`.

You can see this by typing:

```
echo $PATH
```

and

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```

---

This behaviour is controlled in a few places.  Firstly sudo's behavior is controlled in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Your own user's PATH is controlled for the whole system in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and your user's personal settings are in your home directory (`~`) in the files `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`.

In these files you may see lines changing and `export PATH`.

Comment: Is it safe to add /usr/sbin to $PATH in my ~/.zshrc file? Because that solves my problem.

Comment: `env | grep ^PATH=` c.f. `sudo env | grep ^PATH=` would be accurate if less obvious

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani there's nothing unsafe about it. I have `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` in my path all the time.